# Django category didn't work corrctly href not work

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have made a script to display all posts in a category so, when I try to open the single category it didn't open the page and show the article page, I've followed a tutorial for making this code, the link is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o6yYygu-vvk .

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

# Categorie
class Category(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    name = models.CharField('Titolo', max_length = 250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 250, unique = True)
    desc = models.TextField('Descrizione', max_length=10000, blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("blog:CategoryList", args=[self.slug])


    def __str__(self):
      return self.name
# Articles
class Article(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Articolo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Articoli'
    '''
    Classe per creare articoli generali con media
    '''
    title = models.CharField('Titolo', max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    category = models.ForeignKey (Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    desc = models.CharField('Descrizione', max_length=10000, blank=True)
    text = models.TextField('Testo', max_length=10000, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField('Foto', blank=True, upload_to="img")
    data = models.DateTimeField('Data di pubblicazione', blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 250, null = True, blank = True, unique=True)

    class Meta: # Order post by date
        ordering = ['-data',]

    def __str__(self):
       return "Crea un nuovo articolo"
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import *
from django.views.generic import View
from django.views import generic


def index(request): # HomePage
   articles = Article.objects.all().order_by('-data')[0:3] # Show last 3 articles
   return render(request, 'blog/index.php', {'articles':articles})

# Post

def PostList(request): # Articles List
  articles = Article.objects.all().order_by('-data')
  return render(request, 'blog/post/PostList.php',{'articles':articles})

class PostDetail(generic.DetailView): #Single Article
   model = Article
   template_name = 'blog/post/post_detail.php'

# Category

def Categories(request): # Category List
  categories = Category.objects.all()
  return render(request, 'blog/category/category.php',{'categories':categories})

def CategoryList(request, slug): # Show post by category
  categories = Category.objects.all()
  articles = Article.objects.all()
  if slug:
     category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug)
     articles = articles.filter(category=slug)

  template = 'blog/category/single_category.php'
  context = {'categories':categories, 'articles':articles, 'category': category}

  return render(request, template, context)
```

**Urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'), # Index
  url(r'^all-articles$', views.PostList, name='PostList'), # All Posts
  url(r'^category', views.Categories, name='category'), # All Category
  url('<slug: slug>/', views.CategoryList, name='category_list'), # Show post by category
  path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'), # Single Posts

]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

**post_detail.php**

```
{% extends 'blog/layout.php' %} <!-- Import Content -->
{% block content %} <!-- Start Content -->
<!-- Articles -->
  <div class="article">
    {% if article.image %}
      <img src="{{article.image.url}}" alt="" class="">
    {% endif %}
    <div class="article__text">
       <h1>{% block title %} {{ object.title }} {% endblock title %}</h1>
       <p class="article_info"> Scritto da <a href="#">{{ article.author }}</a> il {{ 
article.data }}</p>
       <p class=" article_desc">{{ article.desc }}</p>
       <p class=" article_content">{{ article.text }}</p>
       <p class=" article_category">category: <a href="{{ articles.category.get_absolute_url 
}}">
         {{ article.category }}</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**single_category.php**

```
{% extends 'blog/layout.php' %} <!-- Import Content -->
<!-- Content -->
{% block content %}
 <h1>{{ category.name }}</h1>
 {% for article in articles %}
 <!--CARDS -->
   <section class="cards"clearfix> <a href="{% url 'post_detail' article.slug  %}">
    <div class="card">
      {% if article.image %}
      <img src="{{article.image.url}}" alt="" class="card__img">
      {% endif %}
       <div class="card__txt">
        <h3 class="card__title">{{article.title}}</h3>
        <p class="date__article"> by {{article.author}}</p>
        <p class="card__text">{{article.desc}}</p>
       </div>
    </div>
   </a>
   </section>
   {% endfor  %}
  {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Why are you mixing PHP and Django?

Comment: @MatthewGaiser looks like he gave his html file a `.php` extension instead.

Comment: Use should change the `.php` extensions to `.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function to return the url of category is wrong because the name of "CategoryList" don't exists in

```
class Category():
#---- your properties definition

def get_absolute_url(self):
    #bad return reverse("blog:CategoryList", args=[self.slug])
    return reverse("blog:category_list", args=[self.slug])
```

In your urls.py

```
  url('<slug: slug>/', views.CategoryList, name='category_list'), # Show post by category
```

**category_list** is defined as name in your url, not ~CategoryList~

**AND**
You use the same URL for post and category list

```
url('<slug: slug>/', views.CategoryList, name='category_list'), # Show post by category
path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
```

**AND** You are mixing `url` and `path` in the same definition. 
So, you probably are use django 2.x and read django 1.x tutorial.

Another think (that the devs was commented)... the extension of html files as php is not good, php is a "program language" and html is another thing... but, you can use any extension...